# Compute fourier coefficients with Python?

Tags: python, fft, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, dft

I'm trying to compute the following Fourier coefficients

[image]

where V_{pot} is a previous def function of this form.
[image]

I really don't know what numerical method I can use, however I began with Simpson’s rule of scipy library.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

Nf = 200 
IVp = np.zeros(2*Nf)
snn = np.zeros(NP)
def f(k):
    for i in range(0,NP):
        sn = (i-1)*H
        snn[i] = sn
        return (1/SF) * np.cos(np.pi*k*sn/SF) * Vpot(sn)

 for k in range(0,2*Nf):
      Func = f(k)
      y1 = np.array(Func,dtype=float)
      I = simps(y1,snn)
```

I had this error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Well, [scipy.integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) has a bunch of options to choose from.

Comment: Concerning your error, always provide the full trace back.

Comment: And please change your code, such that it is actually running.

Comment: Discretize the integral, see the discretized integral as part of a discretized cosine transform or a discretized Fourier transform, apply the `fft` and `ifft` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task can be done via

```
Nf = 200
s = np.linspace(0, Sf, Nf+1);
V_s = Vpot(s)
I = [ simps(s, np.cos(np.pi*k*s/Sf)*V_s ) / Sf  for k in range(0,2*Nf) ]
```

But really, investigate how to do this via the [FFT or related methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html).

Comment: ok, thanks, I was able to calculate the integral, however, I will see FFT related methods because the integration has a considerable error.

Comment: First make sure that the formulas were correctly translated into code, including all constants and parameters. The Simpson method has order 4, that should give good results in the lower frequencies. For the higher frequencies you get into the territory of the sampling theorem.

Comment: I compared with `simps`  and `scipy.integrate.quad` and I obtained  two different integrations. You can see the complete code in  (https://github.com/dayacaca/Python-prog/blob/integrals/RollepUP_spiral/dist.ipynb )

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm looking at. The distance computation computes points on the spiral from some related area inputs? Alternating in some way? Can you give a more geometric-physical description of what the model computes?

Comment: Ok, found your post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914813/what-type-of-spiral-is-it that explains the construction of the spiral. I think there may be an error in adding pi to the angle in the lower half.

Comment: This is the geometrical model https://github.com/dayacaca/tesisPre/blob/master/figures/spiral.png, and **s** is the arc of length. I add **pi** to the angle (**phi**) each time that I changed of a semi-arc to other. I really haven't tested if the spiral is constructed correctly, however, the potential looks as it should be. I will revise it